# Trouble with getting value of html element for php request

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to do some PHP server request with parameters, witch values I get from HTML elements in my page.

This is the page code:

```
<body>
    <div style="margin: 10px 0 20px 0">
        <header id="formTitle"></header>
    </div>

    <div style="display:grid; grid-template-columns: 100px 0.4fr 100px 0.4fr; grid-row-gap: 10px;">
        <div class="gridCell"><header>ID</header></div>
        <div class="gridCell"><input id="taskID"></div>
        <div class="gridCell"><header>Date creation</header></div>
        <div class="gridCell"><input id="dateCreation"></div>
        <div class="gridCell"><header>Title</header></div>
        <div class="gridCell"><input id="title"></div>
        <div class="gridCell"><header>Status</header></div>
        <div class="gridCell"><input id="status"></div>
        <div class="gridCell"><header>Creator</header></div>
        <div class="gridCell"><input id="creator"></div>
        <div class="gridCell"><header>Responsible</header></div>
        <div class="gridCell"><input id="responsible"></div>
        <div class="gridCell"><header>Date start</header></div>
        <div class="gridCell"><input id="dateStart"></div>
        <div class="gridCell"><header>Date finish</header></div>
        <div class="gridCell"><input id="dateFinish"></div>    
    </div>

    <div style="margin: 15px 0 5px 0"><header>Description</header></div>
    <div><textarea id="description" style="width: 100%; margin: 0 0 0 0" rows="5"></textarea></div>

    <div id='commentsTree'>
        <script>
            document.getElementById('commentsTree').innerHTML = getCommentsTree();
        </script>    
    </div>

    <div style="text-align: right; margin: 15px 0 0 0"><button onclick="writeTaskData()">Save</button></div>

</body>
```

I have trouble with function getCommentsTree();, here it is:

```
function getCommentsTree() {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost/testapp/php/comments/getCommentsTree.php?ownerID=' + document.getElementById("taskID").value + '&ownerType=task', false);
    xhr.send();

    if (xhr.status != 200) {
        alert( xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText ); 
    }
    else {
        if(xhr.response != false){
            return xhr.response;
        }
        else{
            return "**** you.";    
        }    
    }

}
```

here the trouble:

No matters, what value have an element with id "taskID", line

> withdocument.getElementById("taskID").value

always returns me "", so, my PHP request always returns me an empty result. What I am doing wrong? How must I get value "taskID" correctly for my PHP request?

Comment: Why you don't use a form? Can we see the php code?

Comment: There's no value in the input element at the time you're calling `getCommentsTree`, that is called during the document parsing.

Comment: Just use xdebug in your vscode and debug the code. In your PHP API just add check whether you are getting proper taskID or not. If you are not getting the taskID or not and then return some 400 response. Can I see your PHP API code?

Comment: Because of the circular nature of what you're trying to do and calling the script prior to a value being placed you've introduced a couple of layers of complexity you do not probably want.

Comment: @SatyaNaiduPendem it isn't a PHP problem.

Comment: Notice also, that making a synchronous AJAX call is a bad practice.

Comment: where is your script tag ?? it should be at the end of your body otherwise this would be the problem because your **DOM** didn't load yet

Comment: @Joseph That would not help in OP's case, the gap would still be so short, that a user has no changes to enter their ID to the input element before the script will run.

Comment: aha you are right so he needs in this case any event listener or use form it would be better

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Author this comment:

> here's no value in the input element at the time you're calling
>   getCommentsTree, that is called during the document parsing

was right. I put my code, which the get comments from the server, in window.onload event. Like that:

```
var windowTask = window.open("http://localhost/testapp/site/windows/formTask.html", "taskForm");
                    windowTask.onload = function(){
                        windowTask.document.getElementById("formTitle").innerText = "Task " + selectedRow.taskID;
                        windowTask.document.getElementById("taskID").value = selectedRow.taskID;
                        windowTask.document.getElementById("title").value = selectedRow.title;
                        windowTask.document.getElementById("status").value = selectedRow.status;
                        windowTask.document.getElementById("creator").value = selectedRow.creator;
                        windowTask.document.getElementById("responsible").value = selectedRow.responsible;
                        windowTask.document.getElementById("description").value = selectedRow.description;
                        windowTask.document.getElementById("dateCreation").value = selectedRow.dateCreation;
                        windowTask.document.getElementById("dateStart").value = selectedRow.dateStart;
                        windowTask.document.getElementById("dateFinish").value = selectedRow.dateFinish;
                        windowTask.document.getElementById('commentsTree').innerHTML = getCommentsTree(selectedRow.taskID, 'task');
                    }
```

and make some changes in getCommentsTree() function. Here it is:

```
function getCommentsTree(ownerID, ownerType) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    debugger;
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost/testapp/php/comments/getCommentsTree.php?ownerID=' + ownerID + '&ownerType=' + ownerType, false);
    xhr.send();

    if (xhr.status != 200) {
        alert( xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText ); 
    }
    else {
        if(xhr.response != false){
            //let commentsTree = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
            //debugger;
            return xhr.response;
        }
        else{
            return "**** you.";    
        }    
    }

}
```

Now it works fine.